# ¿Como puedo pasar parametros al metodo que quiero arrancar en un nuevo hilo?

Tags: c#

Supongamos que tengo algo asi;

```
    Thread hilo = new Thread(NuevoHilo);
    hilo.Start();
```

Pero el metodo `NuevoHilo` lleva un parametro de tipo string.

```
    private void NuevoHilo(string item)
            {

            }
```

¿De que manera puedo cargar parametros?

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día, una solución seria con una expresión Lambda, de esta forma se pueden enviar n parámetros. Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo.

```
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            string name= "Jhon";
            string lastname = "Wick"
            Thread th = new Thread(() => NewThread(name, lastname));
            th.Start();
        }

        public void NewThread(string name, string lastname)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + " " + lastname);
        }
    }
```

Espero y sea la solución. Saludos.